# Why my DB is locked when an ADF copy Activity is running?

Tags: azure, sql-insert, azure-data-factory, bulkinsert

Just want to know why, when a Azure Data Factory (ADF) copy activity that's transfering data from the cloud to an on-prem db, blocks all the table.
When i click on the + button of the tables, a timeout error messagge appears. I'm dealing with huge data.
I'm not using a ForEach Activity but all Copy Activities run in parallel.
[image]

Comment: `transfering data from the cloud to an on-prem db,` this means that a lot of your bandwidth is used to download that data, delaying any other kind of communication. That's no different than an RDP session or Zoom call timing out because you download or upload a big file at the same time

Comment: Are you using a for_each activity? As a quick workaround/fix, check the sequential box and see if it helps.

Comment: Are you dealing with huge volume of data

Comment: Yes , i'm dealing with a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ForEach` activity, check the sequential box to make sure all tasks are not running in parallel and locking the tables. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#type-properties) for more info.

> If "isSequential" is set to False, ensure that there is a correct configuration to run multiple executables. Otherwise, this property should be used with caution to avoid incurring write conflicts. For more information, see Parallel execution section.